# How to increase Input box font size in VB.Net 2012

Tags: vb.net

I am using VB2012, How can I increase the input box font size?

```
Dim inputBoxMessage As String = "You are picking part : "

For count = 0 To dgv_partDetails.Rows.Count - 1
    If dgv_partDetails.Rows.Count = 0 Then
```

Comment: What input box are you asking about? How does the code your posted relate to the question?

Answer (score 0):

The following assumes you want to ask for user input outside the DataGridView. If this is not the case stop here.

Create a new form, add two button, set DialogResult for one to OK and the other to Cancel, do this in the property window for both buttons. Add a Label (set autosize to false) and TextBox, set the font to how you want them. Set FormBorderStyle = FixedToolWindow, set StartPosition to CenterParent.

Call the dialog as shown below

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim f As New frmUserInput
        Dim Value As Integer = 0
        Try
            f.lblQuestion.Text = "your question"
            f.Text = "Question"
            ' optional
            f.txtInput.Text = "100"
            If f.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
                If Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(f.txtInput.Text) Then
                    ' Work with data, lets say we want a numeric
                    If Integer.TryParse(f.txtInput.Text, Value) Then
                        ' use value varible
                    Else
                        MessageBox.Show("Not a valid integr [" & f.txtInput.Text & "]")
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        Finally
            f.Dispose()
        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

Or we can set properties on creation of the form

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim f As New frmUserInput
        Dim Value As Integer = 0
        Try
            Dim specialFont As Font = New Font(
                    "Microsoft Sans Serif", 12.0!,
                    System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular,
                    System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point,
                    CType(0, Byte))

            f.lblQuestion.Text = "your question"
            f.lblQuestion.Font = specialFont
            f.lblQuestion.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red
            f.Text = "Question"
            ' optional
            f.txtInput.Text = "100"
            If f.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
                If Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(f.txtInput.Text) Then
                    ' Work with data, lets say we want a numeric
                    If Integer.TryParse(f.txtInput.Text, Value) Then
                        ' use value varible
                    Else
                        MessageBox.Show("Not a valid integr [" & f.txtInput.Text & "]")
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        Finally
            f.Dispose()
        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

Personally I would wrap this code into a class or code module rather than in a form so it can be used in more than one spot in your code.